# wrapper class using visual force pages in a pdf format

Tags: visualforce

Create a Visual force page in a PDF format for a Standard object "Quote", other objects (such as quotelineitem ,competitor,opportunity,account) which needs to called out and custom object as opportunity forecast which does not have a relationship with Quote object.Now how can i call them ..Any Suggestion plz. I shall appreciate if some one helps me out with an example.

Can any one clarify on it

How to create a Visual force page in a PDF format

Related objects fields are called using tags

How to call the custom object(Opportunity forecast) fields in a vf page which are not linked to the "Quote" object

Answer (score 1):

On the PDF output you can start from this [Converting a Page to a PDF File](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm). The key change is to add this tag to the `apex:page`:

```
renderAs="pdf"
```

but you need to take care with the details. For example see [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm); you will also have to add your own CSS to get the styling right. I suggest you work on a very basic example to start with to learn how to do it before you try to implement the full requirement.

Your other questions are relatively broad ones about writing controllers and Visualforce. You should Google for workbooks and articles on those.